# How do I print all unique keys among dictionaries within a list?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

After reading from a JSON file ([Abbreviated example JSON file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cv39odcqn9nk8de/nhlexample.json?dl=0)), I have a list named "liveData.plays.allPlays" containing many dicts with key-value pairings. The keys are similar across the dicts but some have additional keys. I want to print all unique keys with the eventual goal of using these as fieldnames when I write a header row in a CSV file. I will also need to write the corresponding values as rows underneath in the CSV file.

I am able to print all keys within any single dict with the following code and manipulation of the integer 0:

```
with open('nhlbigtest2.json', 'r') as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)
        for k in data["liveData.plays.allPlays"][0].keys():
            print(k)
```

This yields:

```
about.dateTime
about.eventId
about.eventIdx
about.goals.away
about.goals.home
about.ordinalNum
about.period
about.periodTime
about.periodTimeRemaining
about.periodType
result.description
result.event
result.eventCode
result.eventTypeId
```

Can I manipulate integer 0 to be a range or does this task require a different approach? (using Python 3.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `set` is a data structure intended to hold unique values. You could iterate over your list of dictionaries, and `update` a set with the keys from each one:

```
unique_keys = set()
for game_dict in data["liveData.plays.allPlays"]:
    unique_keys.update(game_dict.keys())
```

When you go to writing your data out as a CSV file, I'd suggest using [the `csv.DictWriter` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.DictWriter). You can pass it a sequence of fieldnames (e.g. the `set` of keys, from above, perhaps reordered and put into a list) and it will write out columns for each one. If a given dictionary doesn't have a specific key, its row in the CSV file will have a blank for that column, though you can customize that using the `restval` parameter (to put `'N/A'` or something else if you prefer).

Comment: Upvoted. Or, as a set comprehension `unique_keys = {k for d in data["liveData.plays.allPlays"] for k in d}`